# How can i send an image in Twilio WhatsApp?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send a picture with a verified template and the API with C# but it doesn't work, anyone can tell me a sample of a template which sends images?
I add a picture with the template that I already have

[image]

The error that Twilio returns me is:

[image]

Comment: Could you past the text from the screenshots directly into the question?
That way folks can more easily find this question through search engines and we can copy/paste to answer you better.

Comment: Also, please share the C# code so we can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says that your message failed to send because it was outside of the conversation window, that is 24 hours since you last received a message from the user.

Also, you cannot send media as part of a template message, see [the rules and limitations of sending WhatsApp messages here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio#h_01F63FC8FHAASABF9V1M675YYP), which says:

> If a user has not sent a message to your WhatsApp number within the past 24 hours, you cannot send them a media message through WhatsApp. This means media files are not allowed in pre-approved templates.
>
> This is because WhatsApp only allows sending media on session messages.

So, it is a WhatsApp rule that is preventing you from sending media as a template message. Instead you should try to engage the user to return a response at which time you will be able to send freeform messages using media too.

Comment: thats correct i read that and the way that work is only if the whatsapp user send a message

Comment: Right, you can only send media once a user responds to you. If this helped, please do mark the answer as correct, so that other people can see that it helped too. Thanks!